# How can I save in state the response of an Api Call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to save in the state of my component the data an Api call retrieves, but the data have no time to come cause of the async function so when I check the state its value is an empty array. Here is the code.

```
async getValuesData() {
  let id = "dataid";
  let getValuesCall = urlCallToDatabase + "valuesById/" + id;
  const response = await fetch(getValuesCall, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})

  const res = await response.json()

  this.setState = ({
    values: res
  })

  console.log("Data Values: ", res);
  console.log("Data Values from state: ", this.state.values);
}
```

I'm calling the function in the contructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've to **call the function inside ComponentDidMount lifecycle** if you want the component to appear as soon as the data is mounted

Second,I'd do the following:

I declare, either in the same file or in a different one, for example, x.business.js the function that calls the backend and returns the result:

```
const getValuesData = async () => {
  const id = "dataid";
  const getValuesCall = urlCallToDatabase + "valuesById/" + id;

  const response = await fetch(getValuesCall, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})

  return await response.json();
}
```

Then in the component, if I want it to be called as soon as it is assembled, this is when I make the assignment to its state (and if you want to check that it has been set, you use the callback that setState has after the assignment):

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    values: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getValuesData().then(response => 
      this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      values: response
    }), () => {
      console.log(this.state.values);
    }))
  }

  ...
}
```

As the community says, it's all in the documentation:

- [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount): if you need to load data from a remote endpoint and update your state
- [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate): to update state of the component

[Here's an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-await-react-hooks-67uj7) of how it would work

Answer (score 1):

You're calling setState incorrectly. It should be:

```
this.setState({ values: res });
```

The console.log() calls, even if you adjust the above, won't show accurately what you expect. If that's what you want try this too:

```
this.setState({ values, res },
  () => {
    console.log("Data Values: ", res);
    console.log("Data Values from state: ", this.state.values);
  }
);
```

I.e., make the console.log()'s the second argument to setState which will then accurately show the value of state.

Comment: I have tried that and the second argument (the console log) is never showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 this.setState({values: res})
```

use `this.setState()` to schedule updates to the component local state

**Do Not Modify State Directly**

```
// Wrong
this.state.values = res
```

Instead, use `setState()`

```
// Correct
this.setState({values: res});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```js
    this.setState({values: res})
```

this.setState should be a function : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setState` instead of `this.state = {}`

```
this.setState({values: res})
```